# MVVM - static ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I created some application by using MVVM pattern. Firstly I created couple views (only one was shown) and all of them was using one ViewModel (which contains some List which is used by ListView and other properties)

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
  <ViewModels:UniversalViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Now my application needs to show the same data but splitted into few screens. I mean I retrieve for example 12 rows of data per screen, I read from static Config class that I have 2 screens so default main window is opened (it contains some View as Content) and other external window is also opened (it contains the same View but another instance). Cumulatively I retrieve 2*12=24 rows of data and I want to show first 12 rows on first screen, and last 12 rows on second screen (offset).

My idea is to create value converter which will skip x rows of data and retrieve y rows

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ArrivalDepartures, Converter={.....}}"
```

but how to identify how many rows need to be skipped (ViewModel is static class so it cannot contain screen-specified data) by converter.

Comment: Why is your view model a static class?

Comment: Because every view use the same data but only other parts of it (for example first screen shows first 12 rows, next one next 12 rows etc.). If you have better idea I will be gratefull :)

Comment: They're not showing the same data though, are they?  Why not create multiple instances of your view model - one with the first 12 rows, one with the next 12 rows?

Comment: Even so, your view model cannot be a static class otherwise you wouldn't be able to assign it as your view's data context.

Comment: @BoltClock you may cannot assign it as a dataContext, but you can access a static class in any context via `{x:Static ...}`

Comment: @Lukas It would be way better using proper IoC and registering a singleton instance in it. Otherwise you cannot test your configuration by mocking the instance and properties by auto wiring. Actually, what you are doing caps all testing possibilities and is a big anti pattern.

Comment: So every view should have its own instance of viewmodel. Ok - but where store and update data? It is doing repeatedly every 10seconds and I dont want to do it in every viewmodel.

Comment: Each viewmodel should store the data used in its view. You need another class that stores the "raw" data and that has access to the viewmodels, so it can update them if needed.

Comment: @Lukas I believe there's a big misunderstanding: Depending on your scenario a singleton is ok, but it should be encapsulated inside the ViewModel and not as a static. So you end up having only *one* instance in your memory, but several properties referencing this one instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your ViewModel static - meaning all of the class-variables, properties and methods - if you want to use your class as Datacontext create a "dumb" instance and bind that instance to your view. 
The Datacontext itself has to be an instance - but it is no problem, when the (bindable) properties of your instance are class-owned/static.

It is up to you, whether you create instances on demand or follow the singleton-pattern and create just one instance (and make it accessible in a static ClassProperty.

In last case the Instance itself is a property of its own - be careful!

Answer (score 0):

Use a MultiBinding Converter ([IMultiValueConverter.Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.convert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and pass in a second parameter the skip offset value of the rows needed per page. The skip value can be passed in / bound to a static value  or something on the named page which could provide that value.

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{converters:SkipRecords}">
   <Binding ArrivalDepartures />
   <Binding ElementName=tbTotalRows Path="Index"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try set the view-model as static resource, and then DataContext={StaticResource VM}